# Spring REST MultipartFile file is always null

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, rest, file-upload

I'm trying to set up a simple upload with html and Spring 3.0.6 using REST services.  I've followed the tutorial online but the MultipartFile parameter is always null.  Here's the config and code:

application-context.xml:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
  <property name="maxUploadSize" value="2000000"/>
</bean>
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload a file please</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Please upload a file</h1>
        <form method="post" action="/site/restServices/artworkUpload/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

REST Controller:

```
@POST
@Path("/artworkUpload")
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("name") String name,
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            // store the bytes somewhere
            return "redirect:uploadSuccess";
        } else {
            return "redirect:uploadFailure";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return null;
}
```

I copied the example from Spring's tutorial but no matter what I change, the file parameter is always null.  "name" will have the value in the text box but file will be null.

I have also tried using Jersey and I receive the InputStream for the file but the FormDataContentDisposition is null so I can't determine the file type.

This is running on Jetty as well.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

As I remember I solved same issue by putting additional libs to my build path:

```
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.1.jar
```

I hope this will help you.

**Edit.**

Ok. At last I had time for this issue. First of all, why do you use standart java features for building rest service (annotations @POST, @Path)? Because with Spring it is better to use spring MVC futures for REST. There is a lot of information about this in internet. Here is special part in  [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18.html). Also here is [good article on IBM site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-spring3webserv/). Also very good description on how to build REST controller with Spring MVC is in [Spring in Action (last 3-d edition)](http://www.manning.com/walls4/).

Here how I have implemented simple file uploading functionality:

Rest controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/files")
public class FilesController {
        ...

        @RequestMapping(value="/rest/files", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
            try {
                if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                    // store the bytes somewhere
                    return "redirect:uploadSuccess";
                } else {
                    return "redirect:uploadFailure";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return "/testFileDownload";
        }
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test file upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Please upload a file</h1>
    <form method="post" action="rest/files" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="name" /> <input type="file" name="file" /> <input
            type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

View resolver configuration in dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="file" value="multipart/form-data"/>
                <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I hope I'm not wasted my time and this is still necessary for you. )

**EDIT 2**

Here is [very good tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-with-spring-series/) where described how to build RESTful web service with Spring 3.1.

Comment: I have both of those in my Maven build path (pom.xml).  I've checked and they are copied to the lib folder.

Comment: I still need it.  Thanks!  I'm trying out your solution now.

Comment: I can't vote you up because I don't have enough rep but thanks for the solution!

Comment: All is ok). Just accept my unswer if it helped you to close this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It helped me to connect this library:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

All libs:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring 3 MVC  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Commons file upload  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSTL for c: tag -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

See http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multiple-file-upload-example/